# Can VS2010 cause any problems on Win7?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I want to install Visual Studio 2010 in parallel with 2008 version on Win7. Can this cause some problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have both installed on my Windows 7 machine at the moment, and I haven't seen anything fishy.  Now, I am only doing C# development (no web development or ASP).

If you are really unsure, setup a virtual machine and try installing both on there and seeing if there are any issues for your particular environment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1 side by side in Windows 7 (RTM) and I have yet to experience any issues.

Answer (score 2):

I have both side by side on my Windows 7 machine and haven't noticed any issues (Desktop, WPF, WCF, Web, or otherwise).

That being said, Visual Studio 2010 is still beta...and being such **should not be installed** on a production machine. Use a VM just to be safe.

Comment: Technically speaking.. Visual Studio should not be installed on a production machine period. A developer machine, on the other hand... But now we're just talking semantics. ;)

Comment: Not that Windows 7 has already been released for that matter... If beta-ness is a factor not to install a developer tool, much more of a reason to avoid pre-release operating systems.

Comment: A final build of Windows 7 is available to MSDN members...it's no longer a beta release.

Comment: @Nathan - heh. Good call...but I was talking about your main development machine, not the production environment. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

We have a few machine running both VS05 and VS08 (on vista) so I suppose this combo won't harm either...

Comment: If they are both installed, they used different directories, so they won't influence eachother in any way... if they can both be installed you're fine

Comment: There may be a lot of other dependencies and as already stated, vs2010 is a beta. Installing a beta product to a VM to keep it separate from your dev environment is still recommended.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've met is that M$ VS Version Selector selects VS2010 for most files, if you open them using windows explorer. Since I only test new features of vs2010, while using vs2008 in production, the event is usually unwanted. Big a deal? Not at all, since a visit to "Set associations" could fix it... Wonder if there are settings for the vs selector as well...?

Comment: Installing to a virtual machine eliminates this problem. =)